# Getting the MavenProjectHelper in GMaven script without session.lookup

Tags: maven, groovy, dependency-injection, mojo, gmaven

I have found [this example](http://osi.fotap.org/2008/12/12/creating-attached-maven-artifacts-with-gmaven/) about how to attach Maven side artifact with Groovy scriptlet. I have seen that the [MavenSession.lookup](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.5/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/execution/MavenSession.html#lookup%28java.lang.String%29) is deprecated, and I should use dependency injection. Lets suppose to have the following POM.xml part:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-config-artifacts</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals><goal>execute</goal></goals>
            <configuration>
                <source>
                    def helper = session.lookup("org.apache.maven.project.MavenProjectHelper")

                    new File('${basedir}').eachFileMatch( ~/.[^\.]*.cfg$/ ) { configFile ->
                        println configFile + " attached as artifact."
                        helper.attachArtifact( project, "cfg", configFile.name, configFile )
                    }
                </source>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

How can I have the MavenProjetHelper to be injected into my scriptlet? Is it possible? I do not want to create a Mojo or Groovy Mojo, I want to have it inline in the POM.

**UPDATE:**
In case if it is not clear: the example above works perfectly, but uses a deprecated API (MavenSession.lookup). The question is only if it possible to inject anything into a gmaven scriptlet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ContainerHelper.lookup`](http://groovy.github.io/gmaven/groovy-maven-plugin/apidocs/org/codehaus/gmaven/plugin/util/ContainerHelper.html#lookup(java.lang.String)):

```
def projectHelper = container.lookup("org.apache.maven.project.MavenProjectHelper")
def artifactFile = new File(project.build.directory, "artifact.zip")
projectHelper.attachArtifact(project, "zip", null, artifactFile)
```

Comment: At least with org.codehaus.gmaven:gmaven-plugin:1.5 it does not work: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: container for class: script1417691777869 . Which plugin did you use?

Comment: I used `org.codehaus.gmaven:groovy-maven-plugin:2.0` ([artifact on Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.codehaus.gmaven%7Cgroovy-maven-plugin%7C2.0%7Cmaven-plugin))

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, it might be simpler to just use the [Build Helper plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/).

But assuming you don't want to go that route for whatever reason, with GMaven, you have to reference all objects through the properties object (as shown [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Executing+Groovy+Code)).  Also, GMaven isn't maintained anymore.  I suggest this instead

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
  <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>attach</id>
      <configuration>
        <scripts>
          <script><![CDATA[
            def helper = session.lookup("org.apache.maven.project.MavenProjectHelper")
            project.basedir.eachFileMatch( ~/.[^\.]*.cfg$/ ) { configFile ->
              helper.attachArtifact(project, "cfg", configFile.name, configFile)
              println "${configFile.name} attached as artifact."
            }
          ]]></script>
        </scripts>
      </configuration>
      <goals>
        <goal>execute</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>prepare-package</phase>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
      <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

You'll notice I changed the phase to prepare-package instead of package.  This is because goals attached to a phase happen after all the default goals have been run for that phase.  Hence attaching it to the package phase would add it to the list of artifacts after the package had already been created (which I assume was not what you wanted).

EDIT:
In the light of your edit.  This is actually a problem I hadn't considered before.  It looks like there is no way without calling through the session (you can call session.container.lookup, but session.getContainer() is deprecated too).  What you really want to do is get access to the Plexus container to get to this object and there's no good way to do that without the plugin itself wiring it up for you (and in fact this is what the Build Helper plugin does).  You can add objects to the list of things that it's bound to, but I don't think there's a Maven expression you can use to get ahold of the object you need.  GMavenPlus 1.3 will include this functionality.  I've added it to the 1.3-SNAPSHOT if you'd like to give it a shot (it's in the Codehaus repo but it might be a day before it's in Maven Central).  Here's what it'd look like

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
  <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>attach</id>
      <configuration>
        <scripts>
          <script><![CDATA[
            project.basedir.eachFileMatch( ~/.[^\.]*.cfg$/ ) { configFile ->
              projectHelper.attachArtifact(project, "cfg", configFile.name, configFile)
              println "${configFile.name} attached as artifact."
            }
          ]]></script>
        </scripts>
      </configuration>
      <goals>
        <goal>execute</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>prepare-package</phase>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
      <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

If you have time, lemme know if this solves your problem.  Also, if I've totally misunderstood your question again, let me know :)

Comment: Sorry for resurrecting a dead thread.  I totally missed how old this was.  I thought it was June 28 of this year for some reason.

Comment: Apart from the interesting fact, that GMaven is dead, and you have a project called gmavenplus, I have to say, that your answer has exactly nothing to do with my question. I know, that build helper can attach artifacts, but it is not possible as far as I know to attach dynamic list of artifacts with build helper, which is done by my script. The question is simply about the possibility of dependency injection.

Comment: I mentioned build helper because I wasn't sure if you knew you using regex to match you artifacts for convenience but actually knew what they were in advance.  If that's not the case, ignore the first paragraph of my answer.

As for the second part of my answer, I must not be understanding the original question.  My understanding was that you didn't understand why your script wasn't working (I didn't try running  your example).  The example I posted should do the same thing as your example, and I've verified that it works.  If I've misunderstood your intent, please clarify and I'll try again.